# How to avoid reading in data from a file every time a new instance is created

Tags: java, file-io

I have a class that needs to use some information I have stored in a `.txt` file in the class constructor. However, I don't really want to have the constructor read in and parse the file every single time a new instance of the class is created since that is wasted time/memory.

How could I read in the data and store it in such a way that it is available to the constructor in some way? I could read the file before I create new instances of the class and pass the data to the constructor, but this seems like an inelegant solution.

Specifically: I have an `Email` class (essentially a wrapper around a `List<String>`). However, I want to remove all occurrences of a set of stop words (which are listed in a separate `.txt` file) from the email's text. How can I avoid having to read in this set of stop words every time I create a new instance of `Email`?

Comment: why don't you pass the information written in the file to the constructor of the class?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I have considered this (and in fact it is how I am doing it currently), but it seems to me like there could be a better way (since this approach involves passing the exact same information to the constructor every time a new instance is created). If not, then I will stick with what I am doing, but I'm pretty new to Java so I thought there could be something I was missing.

Comment: I got your point. what you need is to have static member variable in your `Email` class. I have updated my answer, you can see the explanation there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the list of stop words and store it in a data structure (ex., [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)) and pass it as a parameter to the constructor of your `Email` class. You can write a function to read the file and you call it once to load it in a data structure and pass it to the `Email` class constructor every time you create an instance of that class.

You can also create a class to read the file and pass the object of that class to `Email` class when you are creating a new instance.

> Update

After seeing your comment, i guess what you need is to have a `Static` member variable/method in your class.

**Explanation**: Non-static variables are members of instances of the class; each instance has its own copy. Static variables are members of the class itself; they're not tied to any particular instance. Similarly, non-static methods operate on instances of the class, static methods aren't tied to a particular instance.

So, i believe what you want can be achieved by adding a `static` member of method in your `Email` class.

Answer (score 0):

Make a class to read the file. Create a single instance of that classes, and pass the reference to the constructor of the class that will use the information.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the Abstract Factory Pattern could be useful for you here. You can create an EmailFactory class that takes in the text file in the constructor and stores it. Each time you call the create() method in the factory, a new Email class will be created without loading the file and without passing the file in as a parameter. A good thing about using a factory instead of static fields is that you classes become much easier to test. 
Here is how it would look when you use it:

```
EmailFactory emailFactory = new EmailFactory(file);
Email email = emailFactory.create(<whatever you need to pass in>);
Email email2 = emailFactory.create(<whatever you need to pass in>);
```

The factory could look something like this

```
public final class EmailFactory {

   private Set<String> stopWords;

   public EmailFactory(File file) {
      //read stop words from file here and assign it to stopWords field
   }

   public Email create(<pass in what you need>) {
      //filter from stopWords here
      //Create new email object here
      return email;
   }
}
```

If you don't like the factory to do the job of reading the file, you can pass in the finished list of stopwords instead.

You can read more about the Abstract Factory Pattern method here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern

Comment: I had come across this when trying to find an answer to my question, and I think it is probably the better way to go in most cases, but I feel it is somewhat overkill for what I need. Thank you nevertheless!

Comment: Factories could look scary first time you see them, but they are really handy when you want to have control over dependencies in your application. And very useful when you want to create several instances of your objects without passing in a lot of construction data that not necessarily is available where you want to create your objects. I think your problem is a very good candidate for using the factory pattern